# Lower triangle mask with seaborn clustermap bug

Tags: python, pandas

To reproduce the bug you can use this dataframe (made with the `.to_clipboard` method of the `pandas.DataFrame` object so you can import it easily).

```py
    01:01   01:02   01:03   01:04   01:05   01:06   01:07   01:10   01:12   01:21   02:01   03:01   03:02   03:03   04:01   04:02   04:04   05:01   05:02   05:03   05:05   05:08   05:09   05:11   05:13   06:01
01:01   0   0   0   1   1   0   1   0   1   0   4   4   4   4   5   5   5   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   5
01:02   0   0   0   1   1   0   1   0   1   0   4   4   4   4   5   5   5   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   5
01:03   0   0   0   1   1   0   1   0   1   0   4   4   4   4   5   5   5   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   5
01:04   1   1   1   0   0   1   0   1   0   1   5   5   5   5   6   6   6   7   7   7   7   7   7   7   7   6
01:05   1   1   1   0   0   1   0   1   0   1   5   5   5   5   6   6   6   7   7   7   7   7   7   7   7   6
01:06   0   0   0   1   1   0   1   0   1   0   4   4   4   4   5   5   5   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   5
01:07   1   1   1   0   0   1   0   1   0   1   5   5   5   5   6   6   6   7   7   7   7   7   7   7   7   6
01:10   0   0   0   1   1   0   1   0   1   0   4   4   4   4   5   5   5   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   5
01:12   1   1   1   0   0   1   0   1   0   1   5   5   5   5   6   6   6   7   7   7   7   7   7   7   7   6
01:21   0   0   0   1   1   0   1   0   1   0   4   4   4   4   5   5   5   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   5
02:01   4   4   4   5   5   4   5   4   5   4   0   2   2   2   3   3   3   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   3
03:01   4   4   4   5   5   4   5   4   5   4   2   0   0   0   3   3   3   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   3
03:02   4   4   4   5   5   4   5   4   5   4   2   0   0   0   3   3   3   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   3
03:03   4   4   4   5   5   4   5   4   5   4   2   0   0   0   3   3   3   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   3
04:01   5   5   5   6   6   5   6   5   6   5   3   3   3   3   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0
04:02   5   5   5   6   6   5   6   5   6   5   3   3   3   3   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0
04:04   5   5   5   6   6   5   6   5   6   5   3   3   3   3   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0
05:01   6   6   6   7   7   6   7   6   7   6   4   4   4   4   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
05:02   6   6   6   7   7   6   7   6   7   6   4   4   4   4   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
05:03   6   6   6   7   7   6   7   6   7   6   4   4   4   4   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
05:05   6   6   6   7   7   6   7   6   7   6   4   4   4   4   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
05:08   6   6   6   7   7   6   7   6   7   6   4   4   4   4   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
05:09   6   6   6   7   7   6   7   6   7   6   4   4   4   4   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
05:11   6   6   6   7   7   6   7   6   7   6   4   4   4   4   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
05:13   6   6   6   7   7   6   7   6   7   6   4   4   4   4   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
06:01   5   5   5   6   6   5   6   5   6   5   3   3   3   3   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0
```

It is a 26x26 matrix.
I used the following code drawing inspiration from this SO post ([Lower triangle mask with seaborn clustermap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67879908/lower-triangle-mask-with-seaborn-clustermap)):

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

matrix = matrix.astype(int)

# Generate a clustermap
cg = sns.clustermap(matrix, annot=True, cmap = "Blues", cbar_pos=(.09, .6, .05, .2))

# Mask the lower triangle
mask = np.tril(np.ones_like(matrix))
values = cg.ax_heatmap.collections[0].get_array().reshape(matrix.shape)
new_values = np.ma.array(values, mask=mask)

cg.ax_heatmap.collections[0].set_array(new_values)
cg.ax_row_dendrogram.set_visible(False)
cg.ax_col_dendrogram.set_visible(False)
cg.savefig("dqa_eplet_distances_abv.png", dpi=600)
```

However the result I obtain:
[image]

Why is this not the triangular version of the matrix I expected? The MRE in the original SO post is almost the same as my code and I cannot understand where I went wrong.

I'm using `seaborn-0.13.2` and `Python 3.11.1`.

Comment: so you want to show heatmap on just the upper triangle matrix? The answer there says the cluster map cluster similar values together, which you should not be using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linked code works well to mask the values, but **not for the annotations**.

One option could be to loop over the texts and mask those below the diagonal.

Using python:

```
n = matrix.shape[0]

for idx, t in enumerate(cg.ax_heatmap.texts):
    if idx//n >= idx%n:
        t.set_visible(False)
```

Or with numpy:

```
for idx in np.ravel_multi_index(np.tril_indices_from(matrix), matrix.shape):
    cg.ax_heatmap.texts[idx].set_visible(False)
```

[image]